How to prevent daemonsets scheduling to Fargate nodes?
In an hybrid EKS cluster (using both EC2 nodes and Fargate "serverless" hosting), how to prevent Daemonsets from attempting to schedule pods on Fargate virtual nodes?

For context, I'm using Fargate to host cluster-autoscaler (to avoid the potential deadlock when rolling EC2 nodes for OS updates), and Fargate nodes do not support Daemonset pods. Is there some way to automatically taint the Fargate nodes, or otherwise configure the Daemonset controller (which is presumably managed as part of the EKS control plane) so that it doesn't futilely schedule pods to existing Fargate nodes? Alternatively, is there an unconvoluted way to give all Daemonsets an anti-affinity for fargate-labelled nodes, without needing to fork the third-party Helm charts where some of these Daemonsets are defined? Or should I code a new controller from scratch?


...how to prevent Daemonsets from attempting to schedule pods on Fargate

You can add nodeAffinity to your daemonset affinity section to skip Fargate node:
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type
          operator: NotIn
          values: ["fargate"]


Yep, that seems to be the conventional answer, absolutely. If some of my daemonsets are deployed via third party Helm charts, is the only solution to write a bespoke MutatingAdmissionController to implement this affinity on all of them?

Technically that can be done but perhaps overkill as nodeAffinity can do just fine, e.g. additional Fargate node needed to run your controller etc.

How do you add the nodeAffinity to the daemonset if the daemonset is created by a third-party Helm chart? (For example, if it is managed using the FluxCD Helm Controller?)
